# Time Complexity of binary search inside a loop

Tags: java, time-complexity, binary-search

I'm having a hard time to determine what is the time complexity of my solution.
The task was to find the **n** value of **An** sequence - 1, 3, 5, 11, 21, 43...

A0 = 1
A1 = 3
An = (An-1)+2*(An-2)

The sequence is "hiding" inside a sorted array.
for example, the following array - 
**1**, 2, **3**, 4, **5**, **11**, 17, **21**, 40, 65
will return 4, because A4 = 21, and 21 is the last number of the sequence that appear in the given array.

and for the next array - 
-3, -2, 0, 10, 11, 17, 21, 60
the method will return -1, because A0 is not in the array.

my code:

```
public static int elements(int[] arr)
{
    int i=1, j=3, k, tmp;
    int a=-1;
    tmp =indexOf(arr, i);
    if(tmp==-1)
        return a;
    a++;
    tmp=indexOf(arr,j);
    if(tmp==-1)
        return a;
    a++;
    k=(2*i)+j;
    tmp=indexOf(arr,k);

    while(tmp!=-1)
    {
        tmp=indexOf(arr,k);
        a++;
        i=j;
        j=k;
        k=(2*i)+j;
    }
     return a-1;
}
```

`indexOf()` is a O(log n) binary search.

Comment: I'm not sure that the growth rate of `An` even matters here, as in the worst case all values in the array correspond to a term in the series, and thus `indexOf` will be called `n + 1` times (returning -1 after the last time when it reaches the end). Thus the complexity is just `O(n log n)`. If your question was in fact about the growth rate of `An`, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T(n)+%3D+T(n-1)+%2B+2T(n-2),+T(0)+%3D+1,+T(1)+%3D+3) says it is `ϴ(2^n)`.

Answer (score 1):

In the `while` loop, the search space is never reduced as the same parameter `arr` is used for `indexOf`. In the worst case, this means that `arr` contains a beginning interval of the sequence `A` and `n` searches are used, where `n` is the number of elements in `arr`. In total, this yields a worst-case runtime complexity of `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Perhaps one should explain to OP that the growth rate of `An` does not matter at all, and (if this is a homework/exam question) it was probably included as a trick